# Google Cloud Platform Logging: How to search wildcard strings in all logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How does one do a simple wildcard search in all the logs? I hate GCP's query language and their documentation is just confusing.

I tried:

```
text:*MY_STRING_TO_SEARCH_FOR*
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use [regex instead](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language#regular-expressions): `text=~".*MY_STRING_TO_SEARCH_FOR.*"`

Answer (score 5):

Use `:` character followed by the string:

```
text:"MY_STRING_TO_SEARCH_FOR"
```

This seems to do the trick without using regex syntax and needing to escape characters. According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language#comparisons):

> `:`           "has" matches any substring in the log entry field

---

Bonus: If you want to exclude the text, put a `-` minus sign before the key, eg:

```
-text:"EXCLUDE_THIS..."
```

Answer (score 2):

Commonly used matching operator in GCP:

- `=`: equals
- `!=`: not equal
- `=~`: regex match
- `!~`: regex unmatch
- `:`: contains

Examples:

- `textPayload = 'foo'`: check if `textPayload` is `foo`
- `textPayload != 'foo'`: check if `textPayload` is not `foo`
- `textPayload =~ '.*foo.*'`: check if `textPayload` contains `foo` somewhere
- `textPayload !~ '.*foo.*'`: check if `textPayload` does not contain `foo` somewhere
- `textPayload:'foo'`: check if `textPayload` contains `foo` somewhere

For a definitive guide on log query language, check the official doc here: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language